# Generate an array of promises to run sequentially

Tags: javascript, es6-promise

I'm trying to generate an array of Promises to run sequentially. I've seen lots of tips on this but can't get it to run in my use case.

```
export default function generateIcons(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.html2CanvasTarget')
    const promises = containers.map(child => processIcon(child))
    promises.reduce((p, fn) => p.then(fn), Promise.resolve())
    resolve()
  })
}

function processIcon(child){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => html2canvas(child).
 then(canvas => uploadFromCanvas(canvas,
  child.childNodes[0].className.split(' ')[1] + '.png'))
 .then(resolve).catch(reject))
}
```

Any tips? This just rejects and I can't see why

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`containers` is a NodeList, and NodeLists don't have a `.map` method, which is why your code is throwing an error.

Because `processIcon` already returns a Promise, there's no need to use the Promise constructor *again*. `html2canvas` already returns a Promise too, so there's no need for any Promise constructor anywhere (see [What is the explicit promise construction antipattern and how do I avoid it?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it))

If possible, just `await` each call of it in a `for` loop. Because `uploadFromCanvas` returns a Promise too, and you want to wait for it, return it (or `await` it) as well:

```
export default async function generateIcons() {
  const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.html2CanvasTarget');
  for (const container of containers) {
    await processIcon(container);
  }
}

function processIcon(child) {
  return html2canvas(child, {backgroundColor:null})
    .then(canvas => uploadFromCanvas(canvas, child.className.split(' ')[1] + '.png'))
    .catch(console.log);        
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Looks like you want to resolve the main promise when the canvases are available for all the child elements. You can use [Promise.All()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Promise/all) for this.

It should also be noted that the `querySelectorAll` doesn't return anything you can call the `.map` on. You will have to create an array from what the `querySelectorAll` returns - which is a [NodeList](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/NodeList).

```
export default function generateIcons(){
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {

    const containers = document.querySelectorAll('.html2CanvasTarget');
    const promises = Array.from(containers).map(child => processIcon(child))

    Promises.All(promises).then(() => resolve());
  })
}
```

Comment: You also need to add `.catch()` to handle any promise rejection.

Comment: For best practice, you need to handle it globally by adding a hook in your main file (`sever.Js`). 

process.on('unhandledRejection', (reason, promise) => {
  console.log('Reason', reason);
  console.log('promise', promise);
  // Send mail if you want to notify
}); `

Answer (score 0):

As per your question, you can use [Q module](https://www.npmjs.com/package/q) module for that

You need to take an empty array and push promises into it, and just pass this array in Q method (`Q.allSettled`), Take a look with an example

```
const Q = require('q');

const promiseHolder = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
  promiseHolder.push('Your Promises');
}

Q.allSettled(promises)
  .then((results) => {
    results.forEach((result) => {
      if (result.state === 'fulfilled') {
        const value = result.value;
        return value;
      } 
        const reason = result.reason;
        throw reason;      
    });
  });
```

In `Q.allSettled()` The method you always get the result in `.then()`. There are 2 states. One for success and one for failure.

Success => **state** === 'fulfilled', **value**: 'Whatever your promise return'

Failure => **state** === 'rejected', **reason**: 'Whatever your promise thrown'

In this case, you have a number of successful and unsuccessful promises.

There is the second approach which is `Promise.all()` do the same but the issue is whenever any of promise rejected further promise never called.

```
const promiseHolder = [];

for (let i = 0; i < 10; i += 1) {
  promiseHolder.push('Your Promises');
}

Promise.all(promiseHolder)
  .then((results) => {
    return results;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    throw err;
  });
```

In the second approach ( `Promise.all()`), It consists of all your promises pushed from `for loop`.  If any of promise rejected no more promise called and suddenly you got the state of promise rejection in `Promise.all()`.

```
Promise.all(promiseHolder)
  .then((results) => {
    return results;
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    console.log('Promise will reject here', err);
    throw err;
  });
```

I hope it helps, Happy Coding :)